# Aweber form problems with encoding

Tags: utf-8, aweber

I have webpage, that use utf-8. But generated aweber webform use iso-8859-1 to send signups.

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" 
accept-charset="iso-8859-1" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
```

Problems started when I get some signups from foregin countries (e.g. Russia - for example in name field should be "Валера" but in iso-8859-1 I get something like this.
[image]

When I changed to accept-charset="UTF-8",

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" 
accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
```

I get something like this "Ð’Ð»Ð°Ð´Ð¸Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€ ÐšÐ»Ð¸Ð¼ÐµÐ½Ð" .

What I must do, to correct signup those users.

Answer (score 0):

I get answer from aweber support. Currently they don't support UTF-8. They working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Put that code on all of your sites where you have signup forms and it should do the trick (it changes the charset of the document to ISO-8859-1 before sending the data). You need jQuery to make it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".af-form-wrapper").on("submit", function(event){
   document.charset = 'ISO-8859-1';
});
</script>
```